# Touch events on pie graph in swift 3

Tags: swift, uibutton, pie-chart, ios-charts, touch-event

i am currently working on an app that involves a pie chart. And i am struggling to figure out how to make the segments of the pie graph behave as UIButtons. I have found how to do what i am looking for on bar graphs, but it doesnt seem to be the same with pie graphs. 
I am using IOSCharts, I have added ChartViewDelegate to the class header, pieView.delegate = self is in the viewDidLoad(). 
This is the current function i am using to try and use the touchevents

func chartValueSelected(chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, highlight: Highlight) {
        print("Triangle")
    }

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your scene of the problem with the new function:

```
func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
    print("Triangle")
}
```

And it is working as expected, so I'm guessing your problem is not in the code.

Be sure to check for typos or that your `pieView` is linked correctly.

Apologies for the late answer.